# Fn keys are not working

Tags: 20.04, keyboard

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 today, but some combination of keys are not working, for example for the brightness Fn+f7. I tried a lot of thing but not working. My laptop is asus rog strix g15 g512lv-hn221. Any ideas why?

Comment: @guiverc Sorry, it's 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: Are you able to change the brightness via the settings? If yes, then we know it’s the keyboard. If no, then it may be the backlight driver.

Comment: @matigo Yes, i can change the brightness via setting , but not via keyboard